# How would I convert this piece of Java code to kotlin?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I am working on a react native project. I am trying to link this library(https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications/).

I'm having a problem linking it as the instructions are in Java but the android code in the project I'm working on is in Kotlin

Normally, I would just copy and paste it into Android Studio and that would. convert the code for me. In this instance that doesn't seem to be working.

```
  @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            // ...
            // Add this line:
            new RNNotificationsPackage(MainApplication.this)
        );
```

The piece of the code below is what I need to convert

```
new RNNotificationsPackage(MainApplication.this)
```

I tried using this website (https://try.kotlinlang.org) to convert the piece of code and I got this:

```
RNNotificationsPackage(this@MainApplication)
```

When I run my code with the convert Kotlin code I get this error:

Unresolved reference: @MainApplication

Edit: This code is inside MainApplication class which is in MainApplication.kt file

Comment: Is that code inside of the class `MainApplication`?

Comment: @Ferdz yes it is

Comment: File is not the same as Class, also there's a typo in there, is that the actual name of the class (MainApplication vs MainApplicaiton)?

Comment: Make sure that the class that this code is in -- an inner class of MainApplication -- is actually declared as "inner" in Kotlin. By default this is off in Kotlin, i.e. nested classes are not inner classes and don't have references to the outer class.

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/nested-classes.html

Comment: @Ferdz the name of the class is MainApplication, thanks for the correction